# ParentBinding vs. ParentBindingBase?

Tags: binding

What are the differences between the two propeties of [`System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression`](http://us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression_properties.aspx) `ParentBinding` and `ParentBindingBase`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just an artifact of inheritance. BindingExpression inherits from BindingExpressionBase. They both probably return the exact same thing but with the former being cast to Binding instead of BindingBase.

Comment: I actually checked in .NET reflector and the ParentBinding property returns the base property.